# Why is my polyline on the wrong bearing?

Tags: web-mapping, javascript, polyline-creation

I am trying to overlay duplicate segments of polylines on a map via javascript. I am using latlon.js and geo.js from [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

The idea is that a user can input the distance they have travelled and when the map is refreshed, a second multipolyline will be added. To calculate the the point which represents where the user currently is, I am using a known previous location and known 'next location' to calculate a bearing between the two and then using that bearing, combined with the distance the user has travelled to calculate where they are now, before finally creating a new polyline based on that data.

The problem is that this new polyline is drawn incorrectly on my map and I don't understand why. You can see the problem at [removed]. Log in as User2/pass2 and then select 'challenges' from the nav bar. The most relevant code from map.js follows. I am using [leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/) maps.

```
  var userDistance = GymloopChallenge.user_distance;
  var lastPoint;
  var comparisonArr = []; //used to calculate bearing
  if (userDistance <= dist1) {
      comparisonArr = [rioLL,laLL];
      distToAdd = Math.abs(userDistance);
      userPoly = [];
      lastPoint = rioLL;
      console.log('if 1');

  } else if(userDistance >= dist1 && userDistance <= dist2 ) {
      comparisonArr = [laLL,nyLL];
      distToAdd = Math.abs(dist2 - userDistance);
      userPoly = [line5];
      lastPoint = laLL;
      console.log('if 2');
  } else if (userDistance > dist2 && userDistance <= dist3) {
      comparisonArr = [nyLL,lonLL];
      distToAdd = Math.abs(userDistance - dist3);
      userPoly = [line5, line1];
      lastPoint = nyLL;
      console.log('if 3');
  } else if (userDistance > dist3 && userDistance <= dist4) {
      comparisonArr = [lonLL,sydLL];
      distToAdd = Math.abs(userDistance - dist4);
      userPoly = [line5,line1,line2];
      lastPoint = lonLL;
      console.log('if 4');
  } else if (userDistance > dist4 && userDistance <= dist5) {
      comparisonArr = [sydLL,tokLL];
      distToAdd = Math.abs(userDistance - dist5);
      userPoly = [line5,line1,line2,line3];
      lastPoint = sydLL;
      console.log('if 5');
  }

console.log("Distance to add: "+ distToAdd)
//console.log("COmparison array: "+comparisonArr);
  var bearing = comparisonArr[0].finalBearingTo(comparisonArr[1]);
  var userLocation = lastPoint.destinationPoint(bearing, distToAdd);
  //console.log(userLocation);

  userLineStartPoint = new L.LatLng(lastPoint._lat,lastPoint._lon );
  userLocationMapPoint = new L.LatLng(userLocation._lat,userLocation._lon );
  userPoly.push(new Array(userLineStartPoint ,userLocationMapPoint));
  console.log(userPoly);
    var userPolyline = new L.MultiPolyline(userPoly, {
      color: 'red',
      id:'poly2',
      weight: 3,
      opacity: 0.8

  });
  map.addLayer(userPolyline);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using the wrong functions in latlon.js because your map is in a [Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection).

With this type of projection, straight lines of constant bearing are called rhumb lines, or loxodromes. These lines are great for navigating because you set a bearing and head in that direction, but it isn't the shortest path. For that you'd need a great circle, which will appear curved on a Mercator projection (think missile tracks in the movie War Games).

Because you're only dealing with a simple representation of a journey between world cities, and straight lines are easy to draw, you need to use loxodromic calculations. Luckily latlon.js provides just the functions you need: `rhumbDistanceTo()`, `rhumbBearingTo()`, and `rhumbDestinationPoint()`, which should be drop-in replacements for the functions you are already using.

If you wanted great-circle distances, look at the code for the first example on the [Movable Type page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). But I would argue this is harder for your average user to grasp because actual distances don't have a linear relationship to projected distances.

Comment: You are an absolute legend sir! I had an inkling it might be something like that but didn't know enough about GIS data to figure this out. Thanks so much! This has made my day.

Comment: I also need to animate the polyline I am adding if you have any suggestions for doing that!

Comment: Sadly JavaScript isn't my strong suit, so you may need to ask on stackoverflow if no one else here can answer.